# Change the css class when image src is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div and it consist of two different class,when the image source is empty it will have default value.But when the image source change i need to change  class properties how to achieve this. Below is my code

```
    <div data-role="view" data-title="Add Photo">
        <ul data-role="actionsheet" id="ImagePopUp" data-open="onOpen" data-popup='{"direction": "left"}'>
            <li class="km-actionsheet-title"></li>
            <li><a data-action="ImagefromGallery">From Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a data-action="ImagefromCamera">From Camera </a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>

  <a id="OpenView" data-rel="actionsheet" data-role="button" href="#ImagePopUp" style="text-decoration: none;border:none;">
                            <img src="images/icon-photo.png" class="icon" />
                        </a>

<div class="divimage">
   <image src="" id="userprofile">
</div>

<div class="divtext">
</div>
```

> CSS

```
.divimage{ 
 top:2em;
 height:30px;
 width:100%;
  height:100%  
 }

.divtext{
height:30px;
 width:100%;
height:100%  
 margin-left:5px;
 margin-top :2px
  }

   //replace this class with divimage
   .onchangeImageSrc{ 
     some value
    }

     //replace this class with divtext
    .divNewtext{ 
    some value
  }
```

Comment: How does the image source change? Can you share that code?

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your JavaScript?

Comment: I am using corodva capture plugin,in that when i select the pitcure from gallery the id userprofile image tag is set

Comment: If you just want to change the style, instead of adding a class to it, you can use the selector `img[src=""] { /* some style */ }`

Comment: @ChristianValentin yeah, I also agree with you. actually **OP** changed the question (by edit) now, earlier the question was wanting change the parent div class according to `src` value of image

Comment: i need to change both class from divimage to onchangeImageSrc and from divtext to divNewtext when  the image source is change from null to some image

Comment: then observe the attributes of image dom object by mutation observer, check my answer :)

Comment: If you really need to change the parent class, I agree with @KoushikChatterjee. Also, if you don't want observers, you can change the class in the function that changes the src. As it is not a really good practice, speaking of functional programming, you can add a callback or a decorator, depending on your script. As already said here, we cannot advise you well if we can't see your javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know from where your image source will change or that code is beyond your control, then you can put a `MutationObserver` for attribute in image, and in the event if the source is `empty / not empty`, add your class accordingly

**EDIT**

since you edited your question, by changing the DOM structure, so if you want to change style in the image, then only css is enough with `img[src=""]` unlike the earlier case where you want to change the parent div of that image because css doesn't have parent selector so far, so the first part of the answer was addressing that question.